# Important information on new theme hidden due to downvotes

Tags: feature-request

Generally, questions that receive lots of down votes are effectively hidden from the feed - which is probably a good thing. However, this sometimes happens with important announcements posted by staff so it would be good to have a way to keep that information from being suppressed.

One example, is [the announcement of the new site theme](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live). I rather like the new theme but, apparently, most other folks don't, which is why the post almost immediately disappeared from Meta's front page - at least, for me.

I agree with Asaf's suggestion that such posts should be tagged as [featured](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) and that posts featured on Meta should be pinned near the top of the feed.

Comment: I agree. I think that one should probably override the auto-hiding feature on questions tagged as [tag:featured]. And that announcement on new site-changing features rollouts should be tagged as such.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sounds perfect, as that's a moderator-only tag.

Comment: I also rather like the new theme but I believe that apart from the scrollbars(which I believe are not intentional) there is problem with the color of links and up/down votes in the main site

Comment: I posted [this bug report](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28855) about the scrollbars, but deleted it because it was pointed out that it was already reported [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28847).

Comment: There is no aspect of the new theme that I prefer to the old theme, but the scrollbars are probably the worst, closely followed by the color of links, and lack of contrast for up- and down-votes.

Comment: Mark, I think that you should perhaps edit this question to clarify the nature of the feature request (so it doesn't seem like a bug report upon quick review). Feel free to incorporate my suggestion from the comments.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Done.

Comment: Just to clarify, it depends on the way you're viewing the site. The post is indeed hidden from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ - but it is still shown in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: Interestingly, this feature request is marked ([meta-tag:status-completed]): [Meta sites' front pages should not hide questions with very low scores](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62729). But actually what they did was only change of the threshold to $-8$. This post seems also marginally related (although "featured" has different meaning for the main site than for meta): [Don't hide very low-scored questions from the frontpage if they have a bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262255).