# URLs in the new look MSE

Tags: feature-request

Can those who voted to close this as a duplicate please point me to a specific question or answer that flags this point to the StackExchange developers.

In the new look and feel for MSE, links look to me just like any other text. E.g., see the link to [space filling curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875867/existence-of-function-taking-every-value-uncountably-many-times/2877675#2877675) in the answer I just posted to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875867/existence-of-function-taking-every-value-uncountably-many-times/2877675#2877675). Shouldn't links be highlighted in some way? (If memory serves, they were blue before the recent change to the look and feel. Underlining as here is even better, because it works for colour-blind people.)

Thanks to Daniel Fischer for pointing out that the highlighting is supposed to be there but in low contrast. Here is a screenshot of what I see. The words "space filling curve" are in a blue-black colour with so little blue that you can scarcely distinguish it from black. (And heaven help you, if you are colour-blind.)

[image]

It has been suggested that this question should be closed as a duplicate of [Mathematics new site theme is live](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live), but I don't wish it to be treated as such. because it would trash the useful input in the comments below and the other question does not cover the issue of accessibility for the colour-blind.

[On the basis of the proposed reason for closure, someone could post a question "What's wrong with MSE?" and that would kill all future debate.]

Comment: They're still blue, [but low contrast](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/28854). Hopefully that gets improved.

Comment: I wouldn't have known there was a link there if you hadn't mentioned. That is incredibly poor design.

Comment: On this site, the links are in orange, and are clearly visible.  I don't much like the color choice, but at least I can see them.  I'm over $70,$ and my eyesight isn't what it was.  It seems like no thought was given to accessibility in the new design.

Comment: Indeed: all I was told was to use my browser to adjust for my difficulties!  Certainly not a very respectful alternative, if accessibility were of any importance in this design!

Comment: I am happy to accept the closure, although the answer is not to be found in the question that this question is alleged to duplicate (instead that question refers comments on the new look and theme to another question - **and that is not an answer** - this is typical Meta-MSE arrogance.).  I **am** pleased to see that the problem with MSE has been fixed.

Comment: The point is that the issue was intended to be reported there. And essentially already had been reported there when you posted; comments or posts, it's basically the same. And this was explicitly mentioned there; see Jyrki's answer over there.

Comment: "On the basis of the proposed reason for closure, someone could post a question "What's wrong with MSE?" and that would kill all future debate." Right. That's why we'd close that question as too broad.