# Editor's usercard appears above the original author instead of next to it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

When I edited a question, this is how it appear :

[image]

Why am I over the OP's and not next to ?

Comment: Maaaaaybe it's a new feature of the user interface? :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Do you think it make sense ? because it take more place. Moreover with this "new interface" the first answer is not seen immediately... what is not very practical... I'm sure that people who designed the website would have think to this type of detail. That's why I think it's a bug... Moreover, could the downvoter explain ? In what my question could be "better" ?

Comment: Regardless to whether or not I think it makes sense, that's reality. As for downvoting, downvoting on meta signifies disagreement, in this case, with the fact that it is *not* a bug. Don't worry, it costs no reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Recently the site-design changed.

[Mathematics new site theme is live](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/mathematics-new-site-theme-is-live?cb=1)

A main reason for this was to make the site "responsive." This means, at least in my naive understanding, that it will try to adapt as good as it can to the size of the display or window available.

Thus it starts to put things at different places. If you look in a larger window or zoom out this should go away.

This is for all I can tell by design. I can reproduce it here. I make the window small it is as you say, I maximize it is as always.

On a small display it likely will always be as you say. On still smaller ones the "sidebars" stop being sidebars and show up at the end. And so on.

If you do not like it, you can give your feedback on the thread mentioned above, but it's not a bug in a proper sense.

Comment: I have to zoom to 400% on my 1080p display for the edits to move into the "mobile sized display".

Comment: For me it's earlier (but beyond 200). Wow. that's weird to work with that level of zoom. I hardly manage to type for some reason.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I believe the correct way to test is to just resize the browser window instead since [SE doesn't officially support zooming outside 100%](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/241919)....

Comment: @AndrewT. is this still current though?  That post predates the redesign.

Comment: Actually, that's a good question to ask for clarification on Meta SE!... but [an SE staff did ask for zoom level on design-related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311489/top-bar-is-clipped-hiding-site-switcher-on-non-responsive-pages-with-new-desig#comment1018304_311489) (though apparently the issue was not on SE-side). I guess I meant that "SE is now more responsive to zoom", but I'm still not sure if zoom-related bug will be entertained...